# Rcpp::not_compatible when fitting RBF

Tags: r

I am attempting to fit an RBF network using the RSNNS package,
this is my code:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RSNNS)
library(mlbench)
data("BreastCancer")
BreastWithoutNA<- na.omit(BreastCancer)
inputs <- BreastWithoutNA[, 2:10]
outputs <- decodeClassLabels(BreastWithoutNA[,11],valTrue = 0.9,valFalse = 0.1)


model <- rbf(inputs, outputs, size=40, maxit=1000,
             initFuncParams=c(0, 1, 0, 0.01, 0.01),
             learnFuncParams=c(1e-8, 0, 1e-8, 0.1, 0.8), linOut=TRUE)
```

when I run the line:

```
model <- rbf(inputs, outputs, size=40, maxit=1000,
          initFuncParams=c(0, 1, 0, 0.01, 0.01),
          learnFuncParams=c(1e-8, 0, 1e-8, 0.1, 0.8), linOut=TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Rcpp::not_compatible'
what():  not compatible with requested type

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

could anyone help me,please?
regards,

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the input to mlp needs to be a numeric matrix. You can check with `is.numeric(as.matrix(inputs))` that your inputs are not numbers, in fact it is strings. You need to convert the input.